# Validação de data de nascimento com LINQ

Tags: c#, query, linq

Estou com dúvida para realizar uma consulta.

Necessito listar nesta consulta apenas as ofertas que estão dentro da faixa etária que consta na `view` nos campos `IDADEMINIMA` e `IDADEMAXIMA` passando apenas o parâmetro de `dtnascimento`. Conseguem ajudar?

```
public IQueryable<VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS> ConsultaOfertas(string pEmpresa, string pOferta, string dtnascimento)
{
    var query = this.dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.EMPRESA == pEmpresa && p.CODOFERTA == pOferta);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtnascimento) || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dtnascimento))
    {
        query = query.Where(c => Convert.ToDateTime(dtnascimento) <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(Convert.ToInt32(c.IDADEMINIMA))
                              && Convert.ToDateTime(dtnascimento) >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(Convert.ToInt32(c.IDADEMAXIMA)));
    }

    return query;
}
```

View VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS:

```
public partial class VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string EMPRESA { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(6)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string CODPARCEIRO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string NOMEPARCEIRO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string RAZAOSOCIAL { get; set; }

    [StringLength(18)]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    [StringLength(6)]
    public string PRODUTO { get; set; }

    public string CODOFERTA { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string NOMEOFERTA { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string FLAGWEBAUTOMATICO { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string TIPOFAIXAPRECO { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? PRAZOINICIAL { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? PRAZOFINAL { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? VALORINICIAL { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? VALORFINAL { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? VALORPRODUTO { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? COMISSAO { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? IDADEMINIMA { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? IDADEMAXIMA { get; set; }
    public DateTime? VIGENCIAINICIAL { get; set; }
    public DateTime? VIGENCIAFINAL { get; set; }       
}
```

Comment: Ele vai dar erro por que está tentando usar o Convert.ToDateTime() em um Queryable. O mesmo para o Convert.ToInt32(). Coloque o código da VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS e se possível o erro que está dando.

Comment: Olá Gerge, tudo bem? Estou incluindo o códido, o erro que ocorre é este mesmo que mencionou. (erro de conversão de datetime e int32).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, para você entender por que o erro ocorre, você não pode usar o `Convert.ToDateTime()` ou o `Convert.ToInt32()` em um `IQueryable`. Isso ocorre por que o `LINQ to Entities` não reconhece esses métodos para converter para uma consulta SQL.

Você já recebe a data de nascimento no seu método e já tem a idade mínima e máxima armazenada no BD, então você não precisa de tudo isso na sua consulta. Calcule a idade antes e depois compare com o que está no BD.

A `IDADEMINIMA` e `IDADEMAXIMA` são do tipo `decimal?`, então depois de calcular a idade só converta pra esse tipo e poderá comparar na sua query sem fazer nenhuma conversão.

Fiz abaixo um método para calcular a idade e um exemplo de como utiliza-lo convertendo o retorno pra `decimal`:

```
public static void Main()
{   
    decimal? idadeMax = 50, idadeMin = 18;
    string dtnascimento = "30/12/1988";
    decimal? idade = CalcularIdade(DateTime.ParseExact(dtnascimento, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}

static int CalcularIdade(DateTime dataNascimento) 
{
    int idade = DateTime.Now.Year - dataNascimento.Year;
    if (dataNascimento.Date > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-idade)) 
        idade -= 1;

    return idade;
}
```

Após isso você pode comparar diretamente na sua query, mudando esse trecho:

```
query = query.Where(c => Convert.ToDateTime(dtnascimento) <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(Convert.ToInt32(c.IDADEMINIMA))
                              && Convert.ToDateTime(dtnascimento) >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(Convert.ToInt32(c.IDADEMAXIMA)));
```

Para isso:

```
query = query.Where(c => c.IDADEMINIMA <= idade && c.IDADEMAXIMA <= idade);
```